# Magento 2 - Data Migration not migrating customers

Tags: magento2, migration, data-migration

I migrated my data, but the customer table was not moved from M1 to M2.
I executed these commands:

```
php bin/magento migrate:settings vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-commerce/1.9.4.4/config.xml

php bin/magento migrate:data -a vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-commerce/1.9.4.4/config.xml
```

Products were successfully migrated though.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you do not have `<ignore>` elements inside your `/1.9.4.4/map.xml` file that possibly ignore these tables.

**ALSO NOTE: `-a (auto) switch` will attempt to skip missing attributes/tables without warning you - for your first migrations, you should rather make sure the information are notified (without -a) switch.**  *For example: 3rd party tables*

I have just confirmed with my recent database migration:

The following tables are present in M2 migrated database :

```
   customer_entity
   customer_address_entity
   customer_address_entity_* ie. int, datetime, text
```

The `customer_address_entity_*` tables are **empty** though (not sure what contents are supposed to be there, unable to confirm at the moment).

These tables *do have customer data filled* after migration:

```
   customer_entity
   customer_address_entity
```

Additionally - please see the guide **[Here on how to reset Migration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/258209/magento-2-how-can-i-reset-the-data-migration-tool/314139#314139)** I created (when you need to restart for `migrate:data`)

Comment: I did not changed the original map.xml.dist file at all.

Comment: Did you verify the map.xml file and check its contents?  I see that `customer_entity` (and related tables are indeed there as `<ignore/>` tags.   
I think the place where it might be imported are here:
You may want to investigate **`data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Customer/Model/AttributesDataToCustomerEntityRecords.php`** and see how customer tables are impacted.